# Apply button is greyed out in subdivision modifier how to fixe this?

Tags: modifiers

The subdivision modifier apply button is grayed out, therefore I am unable to apply. Below is the screenshot for clarification.

[image]

Comment: Most likely this donut is linked duplicate (alt+D) of another one. So that they share the same geometry and you can't modify this geometry applying the modifier. Use "object/relations/make single user/object and data" so that it is no more linked.

Comment: Why is that. Does Blender does not support modifier on linked object?

Comment: It supports modifiers on linked objects, but applying them will modify the geometry and as this geometry is shared by other objects, this is not allowed.

Comment: But if you link the modifier it is ok. Select both objects (the one with the modifier as active) then ctrl+L and "modifiers". Now you can apply on all objects.

Comment: From what I understand. We can indeed apply modifier on the link object, but it is not good practice. It is better to apply the modifiers then make the linked duplicate copy. But not before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by selecting the object on which I have to apply sub div modifier, then I "make the single user object and data".

[image]

The problem was that I had created a **Duplicated Linked** object <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> instead of a **Duplicate Object** <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

For those who does not know the difference between Duplicated Linked Object <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and Duplicate Object <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> below is the explanation:

1. The  duplicate linked  <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>D</kbd> works as an instance. Meaning it creates the instance copy of the original model, and if I make changes on one model it will affect both.
2. The duplicate object <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> makes a complete separate copy of the object. Meaning that any changes to it will not affect the original model, as it is a completely as separate object.